# Is there a way to publish a message as record is added to a key in redis?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, appender

Here goes my use case:
We use redis appender to write our log messages to redis. These messages have MDC data (**Trace Id**) to track individual requests. We want other application to subscribe to the trace id and get all the messages logged (As they are inserted). Can we have some sort of a trigger that can publish the message as it is being added?

The appender does not provide us with the ability to publish to a channel and we don't want to create a custom publisher for this use case. I am sure this use case is not unique and am hoping for a recommendation. basically looking for something like a trigger that rdbms have on insert.

Answer (score 1):

Redis Keyspace Notifications sound like they might fit your use case: https://redis.io/topics/notifications

You can subscribe to a [variety of notification types](https://redis.io/topics/notifications#configuration) and I would guess that one of those would fit your need.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Stream (v5) data type for storing your log, and having consumers consume that stream for incoming updates.